# YouTube Offline video issue

Tags: google, youtube, offline

Iam going to perform a factory data reset on my phone but i don't want to lose my 8.45 GB of youtube offline videos , What do I do now??

Comment: Related (answer) [YouTube Offline Videos deleted/removed](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/95366/youtube-offline-videos-deleted-removed)

Comment: you will loose that 8.45GB of Offline video data, after factory reset. right now, there is no way to take any `backup` as such for those offline videos.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to restore offline videos as its location is in the app directory which cant be accessed so one possible way is to just try to login on a different phone if it shows your videos then ok otherwise sorry for the loss!