# Where does YouTube's offline feature store video files?

Tags: video, youtube

I'm using YouTube offline feature on my Android device, so that I can playback the offline videos within the YouTube app even there is no internet connection. When I searched for any of the video files, I can't find them on device/SD card memory. Are they encrypting the file so that it can be played only with YouTube app? Does anyone know the specific folder for offline video data?

Answer (score 26):

The location for those videos on my `Samsung Galaxy Tab 2` is as below:

> Internal
>   storage/Android/data/com.google.android.youtube/files/Offline/(system
>   generated folder name)/streams

There might be a minor change to this location or path on other Android devices, but all those downloaded files are saved as **.exo** files, in an Internal Storage of a device!

But it is also true (to the best of my knowledge) that those "offline" videos can only be played using official `YouTube` App, and those videos simply can not be played using any other Video/Media player application.

`YouTube` (means Google) controls the access to the offline file.

The permission is controlled on their server per account basis, to access those downloaded files.

There are 2 other discussions related to offline functionality [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/95192/open-youtubes-saved-offline-video-exo-file) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/95366/youtube-offline-videos-deleted-removed-after-uninstalling-update?lq=1), which should be helpful to enrich the info about `YouTube` offline feature.

Comment: Offline YouTube videos don't vanish after 48 hours Read more at: http://indiatoday.intoday.in/technology/story/surprise-offline-youtube-videos-dont-vanish-after-48-hours/1/407062.html

Comment: @Sanjeev OK, edited the Answer to remove 48 hr line and thanks for hint