# Will changing of SD card result in the loss of YouTube offline videos?

Tags: youtube, offline

I presently own an 8GB memory card. I wish to switch to a 16GB card now, but I do not wish to lose my offline videos. If I copy the `.exo` files, will it still be playable in the YouTube app? Or should I download it again?

Comment: Logically, if you put the files on the same location, it should be working (I don't know, because I can't test it: no offline video support in my country, and I don't have devices with SD card slot).  Anyway, why don't you try switching to 16GB card and and see if it loads the offline video? If it doesn't, then you can use the 8GB card back and have answered your questions.

Comment: No, Your videos are safe.You can easily switch your cards.

[See this link][1]


  [1]: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/97399/where-does-youtubes-offline-feature-store-video-files

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, and based on the Android device that I own (Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 ), the location of offline `YouTube` videos is as below:

> Internal storage->Android->
>   data->com.google.android.youtube->files->Offline->(system generated
>   folder name)->streams

Hence, switching to another SD-card (which is external storage) **should not** remove/delete your offline `YouTube` videos.

Just to be absolutely sure, you can first check the location of offline videos on your device (which should be something similar to the path mentioned above) and then you can proceed with switching SD-card.

But one thing you may note is, if you **uninstall `YouTube` App's update**, all the offline `YouTube` videos will be deleted.

You may want to check more details [HERE](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/106956/will-changing-of-sd-card-result-in-the-loss-of-youtube-offline-videos) and [HERE](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/97399/where-does-youtubes-offline-feature-store-video-files?lq=1).