# Change path to store YouTube offline videos in external memory

Tags: youtube, offline

Is it possible to change YouTube's offline video path to an external memory path? I have less internal memory in my phone.

Comment: Not possible for now. And I don't think Google will let us to change that in the future too.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to change YouTube's offline video path to an external
>   memory path?

This is currently not supported using official `YouTube` App.

The location for those offline videos is something similar to below:

> Internal
>   storage/Android/data/com.google.android.youtube/files/Offline/(system
>   generated folder name)/streams

And more so, `YouTube` controls access to the offline file.

The permission is controlled on their server per account basis, to access those downloaded files.

You may want to check [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/97399/where-does-youtubes-offline-feature-store-video-files/97522#97522) link for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Any external path as in Memory card I suppose. You can select/unselect your download path in YouTube -> Settings -> Offline -> Use SD card.

[image: Screenshot of YouTube app settings]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

Comment: Option is not available on Android jelly bean. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can change  path location to SD card from  YouTube app  → Settings  → Offline → Use as SD card.

Comment: there is no option in YouTube app "Use as a SD Card". Can you post a screenshot to support your answer.

Comment: Above (Use SD Card) option are not in my mobile (lava iris 458Q).

Comment: Sir in my YouTube app there is a no option of storage in SD card how it is possible please send me solution to my offline videos store in external memory: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udqTn.png)