# Youtube Offline Data

Tags: youtube

I like to use Youtube Offline videos because my location often has no connection. But lately I've added too much and it says not enough space. I don't want to delete them. Is there a way I can transfer videos into my computer? Or somehow add more storage space? Thanks (Samsung Tab)

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/112998/1465

Answer (score 1):

Since those downloaded video files are in the `.exo` format, even if you do manage to transfer them to PC (which I don't think is too easy either), You cannot usually change a file extension (like the EXO file extension) to one that your computer recognizes and expect the newly renamed file to be usable.

Having said that, you may want to try few options mentioned in this [link](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fileextensions/f/exofile.htm).

And since those download files are stored on to internal storage of your device, most likely to something similar to below path:

> Internal
>   storage/Android/data/com.google.android.youtube/files/Offline/(system
>   generated folder name)/streams

And, you will not be able to move those to additional extra space such as `sd-card`.

Remember, for offline feature, `YouTube` controls access to the offline file.

The permission is controlled on their server per account basis, to access those downloaded files.