# Backup YouTube's offline videos

Tags: youtube

I want to format (factory reset) my device (Lenovo K3 Note). I have saved some offline videos from YouTube and I am afraid that I might lose them after the device format.

How to back up those videos and save them?

Comment: Related: [Where does YouTube's offline feature store video files?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/97399/16575) / [Youtube Offline Data](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/113014/16575) / [Open YouTube's saved offline video (.exo file)](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/95192/16575) / **[Move saved YouTube videos between devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/138252/16575)**

Comment: if you have already checked the links in above comments, you must have understood how YouTube offline feature works. The bottom line is : All your offline videos are saved in the Internal storage and when factory reset option most often clears that storage.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you will lose them from local storage, you may want to use unofficial client "NewPipe" that allows you to download the videos on your user media folder, giving you total control on the file for your backup needs.

Answer (score 0):

## I have an idea

Try to save those downloaded videos into playlists, so you can save those videos again for offline use

**So the steps are:**

1. Create a playlist (make sure it's private) for your downloaded videos
2. Go to Library -> Downloads
3. Watch a downloaded video (if you have internet connection), don't forget to watch the other videos, not just one if you have multiple videos downloaded
4. Long click on the Save button and click on the playlist you just created (this step means you save the video into the playlist you selected)
5. Dismiss the dialog (using the Done button at the bottom of the dialog)
6. Close YouTube
7. Factory reset your device now, safely

**If you want to restore the videos in playlist after factory reset:**

1. Sign in to Google
2. Update YouTube (if there is an update)
3. Launch YouTube and go to the Library page
4. Go to your playlist where you saved your downloads
5. Save your videos for offline use again (if you want)

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure the asker's issue is about losing the track to the offline videos, but more about not wanting to redownload them after doing a factory reset, e.g. by backing up the downloaded files on the device and restoring them after a factory reset.

Comment: I mean he can redownload the videos he previously downloaded, so it can also work if you switch to another Android device, or after factory reset, so it's the only way you do it without using Third Party software or breaking YouTube's TOS, So for playlists: if he doesn't remember his downloaded videos