# YouTube Premium: Downloaded videos - Original channel deleted?

Tags: video, downloading, youtube

I have subscribed for YouTube Premium and have downloaded some tutorial videos I want to keep. However, the channel owner will be deleting his entire channel soon.

Research online is difficult and I'm seeing mixed results, where some say the downloaded videos are kept when this occurs, and others saying they are deleted as well when the channel is deleted.

Will the YouTube app save these videos? If not, how can I hang onto them?

Comment: I would just avoid this problem and re-download the video to a file, in a way it can be played in any video player. Such Youtube download tools exist for various OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- From [Google Support - Delete your channel](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/55759?hl=en), which addresses this from content creator view

> Closing your YouTube channel will **permanently** delete your content, including videos, comments, messages, playlists, and history.

Also [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/55770), support says

> ...  If you delete a video, it's **permanently deleted** — you can't recover it through YouTube.

(Emphasis added)

- So, the videos are lost. Even if you download them for off-line viewing, you will not be able to play them because they aren't available any more. For more details on off-line viewing [see this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/97522/131553). It's an old answer but still valid because I see many videos which I bookmarked or downloaded go missing because of channels removed / videos being deleted because of ownership disputes (private videos) in addition to YouTube updates.

Your best bet may be to reach out the content creator and explain the situation to them and explore if it is possible that they upload to a private cloud and give you access (provided this arrangement doesn't run foul of YouTube copyright)

Comment: If you do find a way out, please feel free to post your answer here, so that it helps others :)