# Move saved YouTube videos between devices

Tags: video, youtube

Is it possible to move the saved/downloaded exo YouTube files (downloaded with the YouTube app) between devices to avoid having to download them again on other devices? If so, how?

Comment: Unless you downloaded them completely so, that you can watch them with any video player, I guess every device has its own key that is used to en- and decrypt the downloaded video files just like Google Play Music, Spotify etc do it.

Comment: Have you tried moving it? You can say us whether you are able to play the videos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid to say this but moving videos between devices is not supported, Yet, AFAIK.

Here are few technical details.

When user download those videos, using official YouTube app, Android saves those videos on **Internal storage**(and not on external store such as sd-card)of the device. The path can be something like below:

> Internal
>   storage/Android/data/com.google.android.youtube/files/Offline/(system
>   generated folder name)/streams

If you can go to that location, you will find that, **all those downloaded files are saved as .exo files.**

Since these **.exo** files are supposed to be [system](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fileextensions/f/exofile.htm) files, these are usually filled with System info(in another words, the device info) into it. Also, those downloaded videos are encrypted and the video file is split into chunks of .exo files.

Hence not only they can be played on the same device, but they can only be played with Official `YouTube` app.

> You can not play these downloaded videos using any Other Media player.

You may want to check the links related to YouTube offline feature [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/97399/where-does-youtubes-offline-feature-store-video-files?lq=1) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/95192/open-youtubes-saved-offline-video-exo-file?rq=1) for more information.