# How to save YouTube downloaded videos to external SD card?

Tags: sd-card, downloading, youtube

I have a **Lenovo A7000** with **Android 6.0** installed. How to change the download location so that videos downloaded on the YouTube app are saved in the SD card?

I don't have the "Use SD card option in the download section on YouTube."

Comment: Even if you can move them , [you can't play them](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/138258/131553)

Comment: If the app itself is not saving the files to external SD card, there's no way to do so externally, at least on non-rooted devices. Related: [How to save files to external SD card on a non-rooted Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218338/218526)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [New-Pipe app](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.schabi.newpipe/). It has a ton of additional features than youtube like download mp4, pop-up, video in background, and above all NO ADS. Give it a try.. You'll love it